# More than one row returned by a subquery with triggers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I am looking to subscribe my code to listen to `insert events` produced by postgres. My frontend can detect `insert queries` to a specific table, but when I try to return a `payload` I get two types of errors.

I removed some business logic, so it might not be a 100% working example.

First error if I use `notify` instead of `pg_notify` I cannot return the new row. But when I use `pg_notify` I get a query error stating `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`.

Here is an example of the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_link_insert() RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
 begin
  select pg_notify("link_topic_manager", to_jsonb(new));
 return new;
end;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER link_manager_trigger AFTER INSERT ON link FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE notify_link_insert();
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO link (network_id, sender_id, target_id, protocol) VALUES ((SELECT id from network WHERE name='ZZ'), 'zz44', 'zzz', 'z123');
```

Comment: You have more than one row in the table `network` with the name `ZZ`

Comment: I removed the data from the table, now I get a new error: `ERROR: column "link_topic_manager" does not exist
  Where: PL/pgSQL function notify_link_insert() line 3 at PERFORM`

Comment: Double quotes are for identifiers per [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). The notify channel name is a function argument as a string so it needs to be single quoted: `'link_topic_manager'`. Per [Norify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-notify.html): *"To send a notification you can also use the function pg_notify(text, text). ..."*

Comment: I actually figured that out a few hours ago, I did not know there was a difference between single and double quotes. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The answers are in the comments above, one I needed to use single quotes and two I had to delete the records in the database and execute the queries again.